# How do I export the metadata of a hyperion report contained in a .bqy file

Tags: oracle, hyperion

I have 300 Hyperion report files to migrate to another reporting tool and I need to extract the metadata from each Hyperion .bqy file. Each bqy file encodes the query used in each report along with the format and aliases used in each output report, pivot and table.

At the moment I am using the Oracle EPMS Workspace V11.1 to open each .bqy file and copy/paste the properties of each report component.

The ideal result for me would be a flat file summarizing each individual report component including data source connection, query scripts, tables, columns, report header aliases, report etc.

Comment: [According to this link](http://www.cryer.co.uk/file-types/b/bqy.htm) if you go to File → Export → Section in your Hyperion client you can export it as HTML, tab-delimited text, etc, blah. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could get some of the information by querying the Hyperion repository database.  But since the bqy and oce files are stored as binary, you will need to retrieve their content manually.

It's been about 6 years, but...

You may be able to leverage JavaScript to inspect your content and automate some of your tasks, but you'll still need to open each bqy in the editor and add script (probably do the Document.OnStartup event).  There is a lot you can do with JavaScript.  Take a look at https://github.com/dougpulse/IRFramework and http://dougpulse.github.io/IRFramework/Docs/ScriptingDocumentation.htm for examples of what is possible.

Although with only 300 reports, it may be faster to do the work manually than to develop the automated solution.  I had about 7000 reports to mitigate when I moved away from Hyperion Reporting and Analysis (Interactive Reporting Web Client).  I abandoned Hyperion and created all of the needed reports in the new system from scratch.  But I had the luxury of running the old and new reporting systems in parallel for a year.